# Two libraries referencing the same DLL

Tags: c#, class-library

Say I have two class libraries in C# and an outside project that I want to use those libraries in:

```
LibA.dll
LibB.dll which also references LibA.dll because it uses some of its classes.
Project C which references both LibA.dll and LibB.dll
```

Lets say inside of `LibB.dll` I have a method that returns a class type from `LibA.dll` and inside of my project, I want to immediately set the proper class types when calling that method. For example:

```
LibA.classInsideLibA myObj = LibB.getClassInsideLibAInstance();
```

This should work, but I am wondering if there will be any issues present when referencing `LibA.dll` and `LibB.dll` inside of my project when `LibB.dll` already references `LibA.dll`. Does referencing `LibB.dll` automatically reference `LibA.dll` in this case?

Comment: Have you tried it in Visual Studio ? I think you will find there is not an issue, but you should really give it a go yourself in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do this all the time.  Take for instance the `string` class and pretend that's your `LibA`.  I'm sure you've got a library that returns a `string`.  You've also probably returned a string from your library *and* referenced `mscorlib` (where `String` lives) in your main project.

This is no different.

```
System.String myString = LibB.GetSomeString();
```

Comment: If there is a non .net assembly it will not be copied to the released project while deployment I guess.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant "non standard .net assembly".  You don't *have* to include a reference to `mscorlib` so the situation stays the same.  Additionally, the OP says project C references LibA and LibB, in which case both should be copied to the output directory.

Comment: I take that back...you might not be ability to remove references to core libraries.

Comment: I was talking about non-.net assemblies (doesnt matter standard or non-standard). Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241965/tfs-not-deploying-referenced-assembly-to-test-dir-when-on-build-server

Answer (score 1):

". Does referencing LibB.dll automatically reference LibA.dll in this case"

I assume we are discussing refernces in VS projects . Of course all dlls have to be available at runtime

It depends. If you have projX->DLLA->DLLB

if DLLA uses DLLB but doesnt expose any of DLLB types (ie returns a DLLB class in one of its methods) then ProjA doesnt need to know about DLLB

If DLLA does return DLLB classes the  projA needs a reference to DLLA and DLLB