# Unit Testing Unity Configuration File "The type name or alias xxxx could not be resolved"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container, mstest

I want a simple unit test to verify that all Types in my unity configuration xml are valid

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("IntegrationTest")]
[DeploymentItem(@"..\..\..\App\Unity.config", @"MyApp")]
public void VerifyTypeNamesForMyAppUnityConfig()
{       
   var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { 
      ExeConfigFilename = @"MyApp\Unity.config" 
   };
   var configuration = ConfigurationManager
       .OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("unity");
   var container = new UnityContainer();

   container.LoadConfiguration(unitySection);
}
```

The Unity.config works when executing the App.

I have referenced all the assemblies in the Test project

I get this exception

```
Test Name:  VerifyTypeNamesForMyAppUnityConfig
Test FullName:  MyApp.Test.UnityTests.VerifyTypeNamesForMyAppUnityConfig
Test Source:    c:\SourceControl\MyAppMerge\MyApp.Test\UnityTests.cs : line 47
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.5187389

Result Message: 
Test method MyApp.Test.UnityTests.VerifyTypeNamesForMyAppUnityConfig threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias MyApp.Services.Attachments.AttachmentService, MyApp.Services.Attachments could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolverImpl.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias, Boolean throwIfResolveFails)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.GetMappedType()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ConfigureContainer>b__0(ContainerConfiguringElement element)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[TItem](IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(IUnityContainer container, String configuredContainerName)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer container, UnityConfigurationSection section, String containerName)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer container, UnityConfigurationSection section)
   at MyApp.Test.UnityTests.VerifyTypeNamesForMyAppUnityConfig() in c:\SourceControl\MyAppMerge\MyApp.Test\UnityTests.cs:line 61
```

The test PASSES If I make this change

```
var WTF = new List<AttachmentService>();
container.LoadConfiguration(unitySection);
```

But this FAILS like this

```
//var WTF = new List<AttachmentService>();
container.LoadConfiguration(unitySection);
```

WHY?

I have hundreds of unity configurations. Most all of them work. Only a handful of classes require this little *trick*. I cannot tell what is different with these handful of classes/assemblies. The only similarity is that the assemblies only have a 1 to 3 classes in them (VERY small assemblies)

Comment: Because if you don't use type from assembly you don't need assembly to start with - so it does not get copied to bin of the test/nor loaded to your process. You should be able to debug the test and see list of modules/where they are loaded from to confirm that your assembly is not there in the second case. Adding it as dependency OR copy local=true are another options to fix.

Comment: I have it as an assembly reference and it is Copy Local = True. What do you mean by "Adding it as a dependency"? Isn't that including it in the "Reference" of the project?

Comment: As Dependency I mean [DeploymentItem("Some.Dll")], wrong word - sorry... Also if it already set to "CopyLocal=true" it *should* work...  As first step you should see if the assemblies really copied to correct place when test executed.

Comment: Side note: consider adding relevant part of unity config - hopefully someone will be able provide better guidance.

Comment: I think the Unity config is irrelevant.. It works in the app and it works with that line of code, no changes to the unity config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the TestResults folder (as Alexei suggested) and it does not have the assembly! Even though it is set to Copy Local = True.

It appears that MSTest uses reflection to determine the assemblies that get copied to the TestResults folder.

See this SO for more details
[TFS not deploying referenced assembly to test dir when on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241965/tfs-not-deploying-referenced-assembly-to-test-dir-when-on-build-server)

You MUST either reference something in the assembly (similar to my *trick* above)

OR

To get all your dlls:

```
[DeploymentItem(@".")]
```

OR to get one dll:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"YourAssembly.dll")]
```

NOTE: You will get some "The process cannot access the file" Errors, but don't worry it will copy the ones not used. (which is the problem!)

Comment: Good to see you've solved it... (And I even had my wrong suggestion in other thread too - I'll remember that strange behavior of MSTest from now on :) )

Comment: Only the Copy Local thing was wrong, EVERYTHING else you said was true. :)